# Can use regular expression to forward mail in Mailgun?

Tags: regex, mailgun

I am trying to forward all mail targeting one domain to different domain using only one route like this:

Filter: `.*@mail.domain.com`

Forward: `*@domain.com`

The syntax for the "Forward" is what I cannot get to work and cannot find an example.

Comment: Did you make any attempt?

Comment: Tried the way I entered it above and few others ($@domain.com, $1@domain.com, ect).

Comment: Modify the solution to be forward('/g<user>@domain.com').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [named capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), see doc:

> Explanation- we want Mailgun to receive and forward the incoming message to an external domain, but retain the user to user mapping. To do this, we use a named capture. The named capture will remember the “user” and use it in the forward action.

So this should work:

```
match_recipient('(?P<user>.*?)@mail.domain.com') -> forward('g<user>@domain.com')
```

Comment: it appeared that nothing was getting matched or forwarded. HOWEVER, it turns out that Gmail was holding all the incoming forwarded email from my tests, so I need to go back and re-test the solution. And I need to pay more attention to the MailGun logs, and less to what actually shows up in my Gmail inbox.

Comment: A rule with this form: `match_recipient('(?P<user>xyz.*?)@mydomain.com') -> forward('g<user>@otherdomain.com')`  results in test emails being "accepted" by Mailgun, but not actually forwarded (according to the log). So something's not working there.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the website is incorrect; the match_recipient part is correct, but the forward is wrong - it's missing a backslash.

The proper format:

```
match_recipient('(?P<user>.*?)@mail.domain.com') -> forward('\g<user>@domain.com')
```